# Inline javascript unable to call jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several elements on the page for which I am using show/hide jQuery functions. They all show by default but when the page first loads, I only want the first element to show. When I call the method to hide the element, it does not execute any code that has jQuery in it; however, I was able to execute a method that was normal javascript from the same position. The jQuery libraries are included at the top of the page so it isn't that they can't access them. I am not sure why this is happening. I am able to call this method if I put itin an html event like onload or onclick but nothing exists for a first time load as far as I know. Has anyone had this experience before?

```
<cfif isFirst>
    <cfset isFirst = false>
<cfelse>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <cfoutput>var #toScript(path, "pathvar")#;</cfoutput>
        collapseTable(pathvar);

        console.log(pathvar);
    </script>
</cfif>
```

The outputs for pathvar are correct.

Thanks for your help. I appreciate it greatly

Comment: please show the full code (html + js) in jsfiddle.net and add the link here

Comment: `<cfoutput>var #toScript(path, "pathvar")#;</cfoutput>` hardly seems like any flavor of valid JS to me.

Comment: Also, I would suggest to use CSS for initial state, if possible of course...

Comment: @Cerbrus > If you generate Javascript through coldfusion server-code, it might well be valid JS code at the end...

Comment: @Bartdude: Ah, then that calls for a added tag to the question.

Comment: Please show the HTML/script that reaches the browser, not the ColdFusion source. Does it look like you expected?

Comment: @Cerbrus > Well, I was tempted to add this tag, but this actually has nothing to do with coldfusion. Actually the OP should only post resulting HTML, not CF source, and we shouldn't care about server-side code, unless the problem is actually in the function generating the javascript...

Comment: @Bartdude: Agreed, that's gotten me confused...